# Do the agents in Travelers attempt to preserve the timeline?

Tags: travelers

The series [Travelers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5651844/) revolves around agents from the future that send their consciousness back to the present and take over bodies of people seconds before they would have died in the original timeline.

According to the [Wikipedia article on the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelers_(TV_series)), they pick people whose death is imminent "to minimize unexpected impact on the time line". Furthermore, the article says there are protocols in place "to protect the timeline", among them "Do not interfere."

After watching the first episode, I wonder: These agents change events in such a way that people, who would otherwise have met their (untimely) fate, continue to live with their loved ones. How is this not already severely altering the timeline?

**Is this something that will be explained during later episodes, or is the Wikipedia article simply mistaken concerning the degree to which the agents attempt to preserve the timeline?**

Comment: The goal is to ultimately change the timeline to prevent their post-apocalyptic future from happening, right? "Protect the timeline" may simply mean "make sure any changes to the timeline are a result of us intentionally making them, not accidents". (Haven't seen the show; just giving my interpretation of the Wikipedia summary).

Comment: Without finding any episodes where they talk about it, yes, it is explained in greater detail as the series progresses

Comment: @Thunderforge: That's true, they do intend to change the timeline in *some* way. What I mean is: They do, for instance, keep a college student alive. Soon after, we learn he has a girlfriend and lives with his parents. That's already three people whose lives were directly profoundly altered for at least a limited time compared to the original timeline where the college student died. Whatever happens due to these changes could indeed count as an "accident".